# Access file in JUnit test in Gradle environment

Tags: java, android, junit

Right now I have got a Java library which has a test class. In that class I want to access some files located on my hard disk.

The build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}
```

My file is under `java_lib/src/test/assets/file.xml` and the Java class is under `java_lib/src/test/java/<package_name>.java`

Therefore I execute

`final InputStream resourceAsStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("assets/file.xml");`

Unfortunately I get null back. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get thing rolling you need to add the following to the gradle file:

```
task copyTestResources(type: Copy) {
    from "${projectDir}/src/test/resources"
    into "${buildDir}/classes/test"
}
processTestResources.dependsOn copyTestResources
```

What it basically does is copying all the files in the `src/test/resource` directory to `build/classes/test`, since `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(".")` points to `build/classes/test`.

The [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64887) is already known to Google and they want to fix it in Android Studio 1.2 (since they need IntelliJ14 for that and it seems like it will be included in Android Studio  1.2)

Comment: @RodrigoQuesada could be, I'm still using this snippet because I don't want to rely on this 'could be fixed' and then with the next version it does not work again

Comment: I'm getting `Could not find property 'processTestResources' on project`.

Comment: Which plugin did you apply on your project?

Answer (score 10):

Try placing `file.xml` under `src/test/resources` and use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.xml")` (without the folder prefix)

The problem appears to be that the `assets` folder is not part of the test runtime classpath, hence `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("assets/file.xml")` wouldn't be able to resolve the path as you expected.

By default, the test resources folder in a Gradle java project is `src/test/resources` (same as a Maven java project). You can override it to `assets` folder if you wish by adding this in the project's `build.gradle` file:

```
sourceSets.test {
    resources.srcDirs = ["src/test/assets"]
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me. I still get null from `getResourceAsStream`

Answer (score 5):

In `build.gradle`, add this :

```
sourceSets.test {
    resources.srcDirs = ["src/test"]
}
```

In your code, access your resource like this :

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("assets/file.xml"));
```

Works for me.

Comment: Will try it out later today or tomorrow

Comment: `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".");` returns `<path>/<project>/<module>build/classes/test/`. So this is not really working for me.

Comment: But isn't the asset folder present in this folder ?

Comment: It is but it's not the one under `src/test/assets`

Comment: This folder (resources folder) has been copy here during the compilation process, it's the same assets folder, it should contain file.xml

Comment: Nope it's been copied to `<path>/<project>/<module>build/resourcestest/assets`

Comment: Could you post your gradle file ?

Comment: It's the same one as stated in the question (after some tries I did not include your sourceSets.test option). When I do `gradlew clean  build` the files from `src/test/resources` get copied into `build/resources/test`. However `getResourceAsStream` points to `build/classes/test`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out the Google [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64887) I've been looking all day for this...

In "Android Studio 1.1 RC 1" (gradle build tool 1.1.0-rc1) there is no need to add the work around to the gradle file, but your you have to execute the test from the gradle task menu (or command prompt)!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (3 years later, gradle 4.10)

```
subprojects {   
  junitPlatformTest.dependsOn processTestResources
}
```